# Formal substituion of "along this line of thinking"?

Tags: formality

I am writing a scientific paper, where I need to express "along this line of thinking". The scenario is

> Existing literature suggests that A is rather likely to cause B. **Along this
>   line of thinking**, Smith et al. explored those "unlikely" cases where A
>   did not cause B.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I'd prefer 'Most articles in the existing literature suggest that there a fairly strong causative correlation between A and B.' Then your version, or 'Assuming this to be correct, ...' works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original phrase doesn't sound particularly out of place, but there are more formal-sounding ways to say it. You could use "*To pursue/investigate this further...*", or "*In order to characterize this in greater depth...*", or "*With this knowledge..*.".

Answer (score 2):

I'd be tempted to delete the phrase 'Along this line of thinking' completely as it doesn't really add anything. The use of 'rather' in rather likely is also unnecessary. It doesn't tell the reader anything about how much more likely it is. You can reference examples where people demonstrated a likelihood that A causes B (with a corresponding p-value). Otherwise the literature has only speculated that A causes B.